# Gradle DSL method not found：’buildConfigFields‘

Tags: android, gradle

Like the title，my gradle version is 2.10, like this:

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

my gradle plugin version is 2.1.2, like this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

in my app module , my code like this:

```
...

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dazd.supplyinout"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigFields("BASE_URL": ['String', debugUrl])
    }
    release {
        buildConfigFields('BASE_URL': ['BASE_URL', releaseUrl])
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

when i sync the project, i get the build error like the title , like this:

```
Error:(30, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'buildConfigFields()'
Possible causes:
The project 'SupplyInOut' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
```

could anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the method is `buildConfigField`, singular not plural and its syntax is

```
buildConfigField(type, name, value)
```

in your case

```
buildConfigField ("String", "BASE_URL", debugUrl)
```

should do it. It will create an entry in `BuildConfig.java`, called `BASE_URL` and of type `String`.

you can find the documentation [here](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:buildConfigField(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Just now , i solved it by myself like your solution, anyway, thanks to you!

Comment: Documentation not working 404.